# I am trying to convert evtx files to xml using python on Mac and nothing comes up?

Tags: python, xml, macos

```
import os

path = '/Applications/Home/User/CI5235_Joshua/evtx_logs'
folderCount = 0                                                        
fileCount = 0                                                                              #an 

for rootfolder, directories, files in os.walk(path):
    for folder in directories: 

        folderCount = folderCount + 1   

        filePath = path + folder + "/"

        for rootfolder, directories, files in os.walk(filePath): 

            for file in files: 

                convertFile = filePath + file    
                print(convertFile)

                xmlFile = convertFile.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + ".xml"
                print(xmlFile)

                os.system("/Applications/Home/User/CI5235_Joshua/evtx_dump.py" + convertFile + " > " + xmlFile)
```

when I run this, this is what comes up:

> joshuajohn@Joshuas-MacBook-Pro-2 CI5235_Joshua %
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3
>   /Applications/Home/user/CI5235_Joshua/convert_working_example.py

Comment: How do you (try to) run this? What is your exact command line?

Comment: How did that comes up, where did you get that result, in your command line, does your file `evtx_dump.py` include `#!/usr/bin/python` or something similar at the top, did you make your file executable, and your `os.system(...` need a space after your evtx_dump.py

Comment: @usr2564301 I am not sure what you mean but I am using visual studio code to run the code

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong [evtx_dump.py] : (#!/usr/bin/env python) it does have something similar which is bracketed, I am new to python I am not sure how to make the files executable using visual studio code btw.